# Can't assign modules to System->Design->Layouts->Product in Opencart v.1.5.6.1

Tags: opencart

**Opencart:** v.1.5.6.1
**Theme:** Journal v.2.1.2 (http://themeforest.net/item/journal-premium-responsive-opencart-theme/4260361)
**Apache:** v.2.2.26
**MySQL:** v.5.5.36
**php:** v.5.4.22

I am trying to assign the Category module to
**Layout:** Product
**Position:** Column Right (or Left it doesn't matter)

It works in all other Layouts (Home, Information, Manufacturer etc) except from Product.

I changed to the **Default** Opencart theme and it doesn't work either!

Something is messed up with **Product Layout** !??! I thought of that, so I created a **CustomProduct Layout** (just like the original Product Layout) and...

Catalog -> Products -> Edit-A-Product -> Design -> Layout Override: CustomProduct

guess what... It worked!

No changes to Opencart's core files are made. Everything is vQmod (theme, extensions).
I have removed my vQmods (just in case I was doing something wrong)... still it doesn't work.

In catalog/controller/common/column_right.php line 38 I added...

```
echo $layout_id;
```

The value returned is **id=4** (Default Layout). Shouldn't that be **id=2** (Product Layout)?

Also, the value of the key **"category_module"** from table **oc_setting**...

```
a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:9:"layout_id";s:1:"2";s:8:"position";s:12:"column_right";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:10:"sort_order";s:1:"1";}}
```

I thought it was something simple and I just couldn't see it. Now I have 2 days trying to figure out what has happened!

Any suggestions ?!

Comment: Did you check product layout in Design -> layouts if it is configured correctly?

Comment: What do you mean _"if it is configured correctly?"_, I haven't changed it since Opencart's installation!

Comment: Data may get corrupted, or be altered by other extensions, etc. Now make sure your "Product" layout (if it is the default one) is set to the store you want it to and has Route specified as "product/product".

Comment: It is exactly as you said.

Comment: If it is specified correctly then this suggests that something else is interfering with your layouts, an extension or something else that changed your controllers, but finding and debugging it is really hard as you have to check every controller.

Answer (score 0):

Because I had downloaded Opencart v.1.5.6.1 **before its public release**, I didn't had the correct file for `catalog/model/catalog/product.php`
I had this...

```php
   public function getProductLayoutId($product_id) {
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_layout WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");

      if ($query->num_rows) {
         return $query->row['layout_id'];
      } else {
         return  $this->config->get('config_layout_id');
      }
   }
```

instead of this...

```php
   public function getProductLayoutId($product_id) {
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_layout WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");

      if ($query->num_rows) {
         return $query->row['layout_id'];
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   }
```

All credits go to user http://www.opencart-hellas.gr/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=2
Read all here http://www.opencart-hellas.gr/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=47 (it is in Greek).